# Accesing a matrix within a .mat file with python

Tags: python, matlab, matrix

I'm translating matlab code to python. I have a few matrices within a .mat file called 'AK_1'. I only want to access the data in one of these matrices. The matlab code accesses it this way where .response1 is the desired matrix:

> numtrials1 = subject_data1.response1(1,:);

I tried loading all the data into a dict so I could then loop through it to the desired matrice with this code but that did not produce a workable result.

> subject_data1_dict = {}
>
> subject_data1 = scipy.io.loadmat('./MAT_Data_Full_AAAD_V2/AK_1.mat', subject_data1_dict)

How can I access only the matrix 'response1' within the file AK_1.mat?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `scipy.io.loadmat`?

Comment: as jlarsch answered, 'struct_as_record = False' is on the right track but it doesn't load all of the matrices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a `myfile.mat` with the following struct S:

```
S = 
    response1: [5x5 double]
    response2: [5x5 double]
    response3: [5x5 double]
```

And you want to access `response1` from python. Then:

```
>>> from scipy.io import loadmat
>>> D = loadmat("myfile.mat", variable_names = ("S",) )
>>> D["S"]["response1"]   # returns matlab's S.response1
```

If you wanted to select more variables contained in the file than just S, you just add them in the tuple, i.e. `variable_names=("S","otherVar")`

Obviously, if all you're interested in is the `response1` array, you can bypass collecting the dictionary altogether, i.e.:

```
>>> response1 = loadmat("myfile.mat", variable_names = ("S",) )["S"]["response1"]
>>> response1
array([[ array([[ 9,  1,  2,  2,  7],
       [10,  3, 10,  5,  1],
       [ 2,  6, 10, 10,  9],
       [10, 10,  5,  8, 10],
       [ 7, 10,  9, 10,  7]], dtype=uint8)]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: I think he doesn't have three independent variables inside the .mat file but rather a single matlab structure that contains multiple arrays. hence the dot notation (subject_data1.response1) ?

Comment: ah, I see, ok. that makes sense; I misread the question. I will update my answer. :)

Comment: this is the exact way to do it, very simple solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

create and save a structure containing 3 matrices in matlab:

```
a=1:5
b.aa=a
b.bb=a
b.cc=a
save(struct.mat,'b')
```

load .mat file in python

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
matfile = loadmat('d:/struct.mat')
```

you can now access for example b.aa and b.bb via:

```
matfile[('b')][0][0][0]
matfile[('b')][0][0][1]
```

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: this produced about the same result as my code, not all of the matrices displayed including the one I need to access

Comment: can you link a .mat file that has a structure like the one causing the issue?